# How do I keep the coordinates while calculating tiles from a raster with Rasterio?

Tags: python, raster, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I'm trying to split a georeferenced TIFF image into several tiles for further processing.

I have managed to calculate a single tile and give it the right CRS, evething fine so far.

Once I load the tile up in QGIS, it shows me that the top left corner of the tile is at 0/0. It should be arround 483544,5579377.

I suppose that somehow I am missing to give the right transformation. The code looks like this:

```py
with rasterio.open(imgPath) as src:
    tile = src.read(1, window=Window(1000, 1000, 500, 300))

test = rasterio.open(imgPath)
print(test.crs)# 25832

with rasterio.open(resPath, 'w',driver='GTiff', width=500, height=300, count=1,
        dtype=tile.dtype, crs=src.crs) as dst:
    dst.write(tile, window=Window(0, 0, 500, 300), indexes=1)
    print(dst.crs)#25832
```

Before anyone asks, I have build this very same tool using GDAL and calling it via subprocess, but it is a nightmare to bundle up with pyinstaller, so I want to try it this way and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only piece missing from your write call is a [transform](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/windowed-rw.html#window-transforms):

```py
with rasterio.open(imgPath) as src:
    win = Window(1000, 1000, 500, 300)
    tile = src.read(1, window=win)
    win_transform = src.window_transform(win)

with rasterio.open(
    resPath,
    'w',
    driver='GTiff',
    width=500,
    height=300,
    count=1,
    dtype=tile.dtype,
    crs=src.crs,
    transform=win_transform) as dst:

    dst.write(tile, window=Window(0, 0, 500, 300), indexes=1)
```

Comment: You probably don't need the `window=` kwarg when writing.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm !